# I want my page to open in 2 routes. what should I do

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I want my page to open in 2 routes. what should I do.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify two different routes in same attribute,

Something like

```
    [Route("{title}-Q{id}"), Route("{title}-S{id}"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult QuestionDetail(string title, string id)
    {
        //Your business logic

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("{title}-Q{id}"), Route("{title}-S{id}"), HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult QuestionDetail(string title, string id)
{
    // Your business logic
}
```